# Tensorflow, how to generate all-zero tensor shaped by a placeholder

Tags: python, tensorflow

I wanted to use the `tf.where` function in tensorflow.

`selected_data = tf.where(mask,some_place_holder,zeros)`

however, when I wrote

`zeros = tf.zeros(some_place_holder.shape)`

error occurs:

`ValueError: Cannot convert a partially known TensorShape to a Tensor: (?, 1000, 10)`

I also tried to use `tf.fill`, but similar errors occured.

Well, there indeed some solution such as

`zeros = tf.matmul(some_place_holder , tf.zeros([some_place_holder.shape[-1],some_place_holder.shape[-1]]))`

but is there any better solution?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `tf.zeros_like(some_place_holder)`:

```
input_tensor = tf.placeholder(tf.int8, shape=[None, 3])

zeros = tf.zeros_like(input_tensor)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(zeros, feed_dict={input_tensor: [[1,2,3]]}))
# [[0 0 0]]
```

Comment: module tensorflow has no attribute placeholder